# link is failing on xlnt.test project with 10 unresoved extrenals :

Tags: c++

Build started: Project: xlnt.test, Configuration: Release x64
...
runner-autogen.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl xml::qname::~qname(void)" (__imp_??1qname@xml@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "int `public: __cdecl std::pair<class xml::qname const ,struct xml::parser::attribute_value_type>::pair<class xml::qname const ,struct xml::parser::attribute_value_type>(struct pair<class xml::qname const ,struct xml::parser::attribute_value_type>::dtor$0 const &)'::`1'::dtor$0" (?dtor$0@?0???0?$pair@$$CBVqname@xml@@Uattribute_value_type@parser@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBU01@@Z@4HA)
4>     1>
4>runner-autogen.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl xml::qname::qname(class xml::qname const &)" (__imp_??0qname@xml@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl std::pair::pair(struct std::pair const &)" (??0?$pair@$$CBVqname@xml@@Uattribute_value_type@parser@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBU01@@Z)
4>     1>
4>runner-autogen.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl xml::parser::parser(void const *,unsigned __int64,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,unsigned short)" (__imp_??0parser@xml@@QEAA@PEBX_KAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@G@Z) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl xml_helper::compare_xml_exact(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,bool)" (?compare_xml_exact@xml_helper@@SA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0_N@Z)
4>     1>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This post looks really messy, can you edit it so that the error message is easier to read? Hint: try formatting it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building libstudxml-1.0.1 (http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/libstudxml/ ) and linking xlnt.test with that library resolves the undefined symbol issue. 
Also note that on my system xlnt does not link successfully with libstudxml-1.0.1 and it has to be linked with xlnt-master\third-party\libstudxml...\libstudxml.lib